# Can the text inside a td resize along with the td? (be a percentage of its height?)

Tags: javascript, css, html, text, resize

I have a table which is 100% of the screen, and inside it there are 3x3 = 9 cells, 33% each. 
So far so good. Its a clean, scalable tic-tac-toe thing.

The problem is that the text inside the TDs does not scale along.

Is there some way to say "I want the text size to be 30% of the height of the TD" ? Or something

PS: I tried font-size:50%, but it does not work. This means 50% of the parent font size, which is some fixed value in pixels. So its not dynamic.

Comment: You sould really not use tables for layout. This is an extremely bad practice.

Comment: @Ood Whether using tables or divs, question remains the same. "Is it possible to dynamically size fonts according to their container"?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use em instead of %, 2 em would mean double size and 0.5 em would be 50%.

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/cmAcz/

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with JavaScript.

```
<body onload="resizeFontSize();" onresize="resizeFontSize();">
<div style="width: 100%" id="el">Content</div>
</body>
```

And the function:

```
function resizeFontSize(){

element = document.getElementById('el');
element.style.fontSize = (element.offsetHeight * 0.3) + 'px'; 

}
```

Comment: The code works in Quirks Mode. To make it work in Standards Mode as well, you need append a unit to the `font-size` value: `element.style.fontSize = (element.offsetHeight * 0.3) + 'px';`. And the example does not really work at all, since `div` element has empty content.

Comment: Fixed those two issues.

Answer (score 1):

As I've already provided you a demonstration in the comment, but I read that you wanted the `font-size` based on `height` of each `td` i.e `30%` of `td` so there is no way you can do that using pure CSS, you will have to use Javascript or jQuery to achieve that...

```
$('table tr td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('font-size', $(this).height()*0.3 + 'px');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmAcz/1/)

Comment: I thinks your answer matches the question `Is there some way to say "I want the text size to be 30% of the height of the TD"?` - so plus 1 from me. But based on `a table which is 100% of the screen` i believe he wants to have bigger text if the user has a bigger screen.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree thank you and if that's the case than width matters, so for that, I've already provided one example in the comment.. here's the link if you want :) http://jsfiddle.net/cmAcz/